# POST data sent with ajax doesn't trigger ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") in 2nd PHP File

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to make some sort of simple text chat.

I have two PHP files (`index.php` and `send.php`) and a javascript script (`script.js`).

In `index.php`, i got the following form:

```
<form id="formSend" method="post">
  <input id="inputMsg" class="form-control input-msg" type="text" name="msg" autocomplete="off">
  <button id="btnSend" class="btn btn-success button-send" type="submit" name="send">Send</button>
</form>
```

To prevent the page from reloading, the data is sent with a ajax request in my javascript file:

```
$('#formSend').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url="send.php";
  var posting = $.post(url, {msg: $('#input-msg').val() });
  posting.done(function(data){
    $('#inputMsg').val('');
    console.log('success');
  });
});
```

The ajax request works (success is logged in the console), but in `send.php` 
nothing happens.

Im using the following code in `send.php`:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
  if(isset($_POST['msg']) && !empty(trim($_POST['msg']))){
    $msg = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["msg"]));
    $check = true;
  }
  else{
    $check = false;
  }

  if ($check = true) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO chat(message) values (?)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    if($stmt===false){
      $error = 'Database error';
    }
    if(!$stmt->bind_param('s', $msg)){
      $error = 'Database error';
    }
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
      $error = 'Database error' . $mysqli->error;
    }
    if(empty($error)){
      $mysqli->close();
      $success = 'Success';
    }
  }
}
```

Am i missing something? I really don't know why its not working...

Comment: Well maybe you should _output_ the contents of your $error/$success variables, to see what has actually happened …?

Comment: not need to add `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` try it

Comment: if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     // The request is using the POST method
}

Comment: `if($check = true)` should read `if($check)` or `if($check == true)`

Comment: @CBroe I did, but there was no output because it didn't even go through...

Comment: So you obviously did something like `var_dump($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]);` at the very beginning of the script next, right?

Comment: I'm new to the js `.submit()` method, havent bothered to look it up. I just use `.click()`. I see a lot of trivial things in your code, `$check = true`, `$stmt->bind_param('s', $msg))` perfectly fine however you already know that `$msg` is set, theirfor the `prepare()` cannot fail, thus obsolete. `execute()` however may fail, put more focus on that. Also, you fail to close the connection *when* an error happens. Not that it matters that much but i just find that strange.

Comment: @CBroe no, i used a iframe to display send.php, (I'm still on index.php) and no echos in the `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` appeared on the page

Comment: @NiravJoshi Still not working...

Comment: What sense does it make to use an iframe here, when the request you are making to that script is an AJAX request …? And what exactly does that even mean - did you just put `<iframe src="send.php"></iframe>` into your page? Well then of course your if condition won’t be true, because the browser makes a good old _GET_ request to load the document to display inside the iframe.

Comment: @Adder Uh thank you, fixed it but still not working :(

Comment: @NiravJoshi Are you kidding me? You want the script to fire as well when I send a `head`, `put`, `delete`, `options` or `connect`? It is perfectly legit to have that statement in a code and there is nothing wrong with it. Much more secure than what you're suggesting.

Comment: @CBroe Ok, I didnt know that... I just thought it is a good idea to display the echos from another .php file. But still, it should write the data into the database. The connection works and i can write into the table chat. Any ideas?

Comment: @CBroe Can you elaborate on `iframe`? I see nothing of that in the OP's code. Noor do I see an edit link. My computer neither, `crtl+f & frame` does not result in a match. I find that a strange upvote.

Comment: @Xorifelse Thats because i didnt paste the whole HTML code into the question, just the form. If you want, i provide the whole code.

Comment: @TeemoBiceps What I want is a [mcve].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147365/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-teemobiceps).

Comment: _“Any ideas?”_ - well do as I said - output what the variable you are checking against _actually_ contains, and then check what the result was in your browser dev tools, network panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id="inputMsg" class="form-contr .... >
```

And

```
var posting = $.post(url, {msg: $('#input-msg').val() });
```

Does not match.

Remove the `-` and Capitalize `M`

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time in the chat, and thank you again for your patience :)

Comment: The only thing I'm sorry about is that I wasn't able to spot it sooner. At the very least, I hope you learned how to diagnose a script so stuff like this doesn't happen so much in the future.